# Canvas gets cut when generating multiple page PDFs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF from an HTML page using jsPDF and html2canvs. In one section of the project works well and the pdf is generated as needed. One other section though it's too big and the canvas gets cut at the bottom at the document. I've tried to implement a multiple page solution, however, the image still gets cut and data is not shown.

The solution that I tried is this one but with no avail:

```
const data = document.getElementById('pdfPage_');
html2canvas(data).then((canvas:any) => {
  const imgWidth = 208;
  const pageHeight = 295;
  const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
  let heightLeft = imgHeight;
  let position = 0;
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm');
  doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  doc.save('Downld.pdf');
});
```

For reference I am using Angular 6

PDF to be readable with all elements showing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, as the page will still appear to be cropped, but at least all the data will be visible on the next page. It consists in removing extra pixels to the position in the while loop:

```js
const data = document.getElementById('pdfPage_');

const pageOffsetY = 24;

html2canvas(data).then((canvas:any) => {
  const imgWidth = 208;
  const pageHeight = 295;
  const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
  let heightLeft = imgHeight;
  let position = 0;
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm');
  doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight - pageOffsetY;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  doc.save('Downld.pdf');
});
```